# Tweened component prop

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have this CircularProgressBar.svelte component and I want to animate when the percentage changes.
This is how CircularProgressBar.svelte is defined:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    /**
     * @type string
     */
    export let percentage

    // ...other props...

    // Make sure that it doesn't get created again
    onMount(() => {
        console.log("I was created!");
    });
</script>

<!-- some html -->

<style>
/* some gradients */
</style>
```

And that's how I use it:

```html
{#each pump_data as pump, i (pump.id)}
    <tr class={i % 2 === 1 ? 'bg-gray-100' : ''} animate:flip>
        <td class="text-center">{pump.id}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <CircularProgressBar percentage={pump.percentage} /> {pump.display_time}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">{pump.medication}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{pump.type}</td>
    </tr>
{/each}
```

What I want to do is, when percentage changes from 66 to 67 for example, to use something from `svelte/motion` like `tweened`.
I've verified that the components doesn't get created again but, instead, only that value changes (or, at least, i think)

Is there a way to do something like `onPropValueChange()` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything like that. Just create a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive).

```js
const animatedPercentage = tweened(...);

$: animatedPercentage.set(
  percentage,
  { duration: 500, easing: ... },
);
```

Animation properties can also be set as part of the defaults if they are static, then you can also use `$store` instead:

```js
$: $animatedPercentage = percentage;
```

Incidentally I created [something like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/76c844dfb3e140d380be439f0572fbfb?version=4.2.0) before.